# Form validation with Selenium (Java)

Tags: java, selenium

I wanted to know how others validate forms in Selenium (Java).

Part of my smoke test suite is to validate a form. The test would be to...

1. check that the fields and buttons that should be there are actually there (i.e. nothing is missing)
2. check that no additional fields or buttons are present on the form

Presently I create a List of "expected" WebElements and I also create a List of "actual" WebElements. Then the two lists are compared. If they are equal the form is correct. This test does not validate that data can be entered.

Is there a better or more efficient way to do this test?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can validate both in one go using [Serialization](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/serialization-in-java/).

Just serialize `List<WebElement> formElements` initially by using xpath `//form[@id='form_id']//*`

Deserialize this `formElements` and compare them in every smoke test.